# Plot an arbitrary data column vs another column

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

Please consider the following list:

```
v1v2 = {{-10, 8.04, 8.046, 0.006}, {-9, 9.021`, 
7.37`, -1.6510000000000007`}, {-8, 6.756`, 8.527`, 
1.770999999999999`}, {-7, 8.058`, 6.178`, -1.88`}, {-6, 5.625`, 
7.635`, 2.01`}, {-5, 5.326`, 7.626`, 2.3000000000000007`}, {-4, 
5.013`, 7.5`, 2.487`}, {-3, 4.68`, 7.319`, 
2.6390000000000002`}, {-2, 7.121`, 7.19`, 
0.06899999999999995`}, {-1, 6.914`, 6.919`, 
0.004999999999999893`}, {0, 3.504`, 5.468`, 1.964`}, {1, 3.08`, 
4.831`, 1.7510000000000003`}, {2, 2.284`, 4.396`, 2.112`}, {3, 
1.928`, 4.201`, 2.2729999999999997`}, {4, 1.928`, 4.201`, 
2.2729999999999997`}, {5, 1.596`, 4.018`, 
2.4219999999999997`}, {6, 1.286`, 3.847`, 2.561`}, {0.995`, 
3.686`, 2.691`}, {0.724`, 3.531`, 2.8070000000000004`}, {0.469`, 
3.387`, 2.918`}, {0.23`, 3.249`, 3.019`}};
```

How can I plot an arbitrary column versus another arbitrary column. For example the third column, vs the first column: `{{-10,8.046},{-9,7.37},{-8,8.527}...}`

Comment: `ListLinePlot[v1v2[[All,{1,3}]]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Edit

Here a function that will do it.

```
plotFrom2Col[data_, xCol_, yCol_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Module[{pts},
    pts = Extract[#, {{xCol}, {yCol}}] & /@ data;
    ListLinePlot[pts,
      Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[pts]},
      opts]]
```

Then with

```
data = 
  {{-10, 8.04, 8.046, 0.006}, {-9, 9.021, 7.37, -1.65}, {-8, 6.756, 8.527, 1.7701}, 
   {-7, 8.058, 6.178, -1.88}, {-6, 5.625, 7.635, 2.01}, {-5, 5.326, 7.626, 2.3}, 
   {-4, 5.013, 7.5, 2.487}, {-3, 4.68, 7.319, 2.639,}, {-2, 7.121, 7.19, 0.069}, 
   {-1, 6.914, 6.919, 0.005}, {0, 3.504, 5.468, 1.964}, {1, 3.08, 4.831, 1.751}, 
   {2, 2.284, 4.396, 2.112}, {3, 1.928, 4.201, 2.273}, {4, 1.928, 4.201, 2.273}, 
   {5, 1.596, 4.018, 2.422}, {6, 1.286, 3.847, 2.561}, {7, 0.995, 3.686, 2.691}, 
   {8, 0.724, 3.531, 2.807}, {9, 0.469, 3.387, 2.918}, {10, 0.23, 3.249, 3.019}};

plotFrom2Col[data, 1, 3]
```

[image: plot13]

`plotFrom2Col` accepts plot options

```
plotFrom2Col[data, 3, 2, PlotStyle -> Dashed, Frame -> True]
```

[image: plot32]

#### Update

I got to thinking it would be a good idea to make showing the data points optional rather than mandatory as it is above. As usual there are multiple ways to modify `plotFrom2Col` to provide this additional capability. I experimented with two different ways and finally decided that the following is the better of the two.

```
Clear[plotFrom2Col]
plotFrom2Col[data_, xCol_, yCol_, showPts : (True | False) : True, 
             opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Module[{pts, opseq},
    pts = Extract[#, {{xCol}, {yCol}}] & /@ data;
    opseq =
      If[showPts,
       {Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[pts]}, opts},
       {opts}];
   ListLinePlot[pts, opseq]]
```

Default usage.

```
plotFrom2Col[data, 1, 3]
```

[image: plot13]

`ListLinePlot` options may be given.

```
plotFrom2Col[data, 1, 3, PlotStyle -> Dashed]
```

[image: plot13_2]

The default epilog may be suppressed.

plotFrom2Col[data, 1, 3, False, PlotStyle -> Dashed]

[image: plot13_3]

The default epilog may be overridden.

```
plotFrom2Col[data, 1, 3, False,
  PlotStyle -> Dashed, 
  Epilog -> {Text["Column 3 plotted\nagainst column 1", Scaled[{.2, .3}]]}]
```

[image: plot13_4]

The data points can be shown without the plot.

```
plotFrom2Col[data, 1, 3, PlotStyle -> None, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image: plot13_5]

Answer (score 5):

Here is a [`Dataset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset) approach:

```
ds = Dataset[v1v2];

ds[ListLinePlot, {1, 3}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
(* 3rd against first column *)

data13 = Transpose[{v1v2[[All, 1]], v1v2[[All, 3]]}];

ListLinePlot[data13, FrameLabel -> {"col 1", "col 3"}, Frame -> True, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[data]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Apply` to extract the columns you want (here, 3 and 1) and place them a new list that can be entered as input to `ListLinePlot`.

```
data13 = Apply[{#1, #3} &, v1v2, 1];

ListLinePlot[data13, FrameLabel -> {"col 1", "col 3"}, Frame -> True, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[data13]}]
```

[image]

This is easily modified to work with rows:

```
data13r = Apply[{#1, #3} &, v1v2] // Transpose;

ListLinePlot[data13r, FrameLabel -> {"row 1", "row 3"}, Frame -> True,
  Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[data13r]}]
```

[image]